# Network doesn't come back up after connection loss

Tags: networking, server, netplan, network-bonding

I've successfully gotten my setup working with a 2Gbps connection to the rest of my network through a Unifi switch via bond0 (enp6s0 & enp7s0 in LACP) using netplan.

The problem I'm running into right now is losses of connection. When I update my switch firmware or need to unplug it etc, the server doesn't come back up on the network. In addition to that, when I pull one cable from the nic and replug it after a few moments, that interface shows good connection, but no traffic while the other is working just fine.

The only way that I have found to get it back is to do a full reset.

I've tried `netplan --debug apply`, and it tells me basically that everything is ok, and that nothing needs done.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if I'm an idiot and why. Also please let me know if there are any other problems in my .yaml that stand out.

My network configuration .yaml:

```
network:
 version: 2
 renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
   enp6s0:
     match:
       macaddress: 00:25:90:04:f6:5a
   enp7s0:
     match:
       macaddress: 00:25:90:04:f6:5b
 bonds:
   bond0:
     interfaces:
       - enp6s0
       - enp7s0
     parameters:
       mode: 802.3ad
       lacp-rate: fast
       transmit-hash-policy: layer2+3
     dhcp4: true
```

Output from `netplan --debug apply` when enp6s0 was unplugged and replugged:

```
** (generate:11383): DEBUG: 22:04:11.180: Processing input file 
//etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:11383): DEBUG: 22:04:11.180: starting new processing pass
** (generate:11383): DEBUG: 22:04:11.180: Processing input file 
//etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..
** (generate:11383): DEBUG: 22:04:11.180: starting new processing pass
** (generate:11383): DEBUG: 22:04:11.180: enp7s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:11383): DEBUG: 22:04:11.180: bond0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:11383): DEBUG: 22:04:11.180: enp6s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:11383): DEBUG: 22:04:11.180: Generating output files..
** (generate:11383): DEBUG: 22:04:11.180: NetworkManager: definition enp7s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:11383): DEBUG: 22:04:11.181: NetworkManager: definition bond0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:11383): DEBUG: 22:04:11.181: NetworkManager: definition enp6s0 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration exists, restarting networkd
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:device enp7s0 operstate is up, not replugging
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp7s0
DEBUG:device veth1ec269a operstate is up, not replugging
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth1ec269a
DEBUG:device veth6251ba2 operstate is up, not replugging
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth6251ba2
DEBUG:device bond0 operstate is up, not replugging
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for bond0
DEBUG:device enp6s0 operstate is up, not replugging
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp6s0
DEBUG:device docker0 operstate is up, not replugging
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for docker0
DEBUG:device lo operstate is unknown, not replugging
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
```

Output of `ip a` after enp6s0 was unplugged and replugged:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:93:c6:63:32:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:93:c6:63:32:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4a:93:c6:63:32:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.25.8/24 brd 172.16.25.255 scope global dynamic bond0
       valid_lft 85571sec preferred_lft 85571sec
    inet6 fe80::4893:c6ff:fe63:3284/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:46:ee:01:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:46ff:feee:1b9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: veth1ec269a@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether 0a:40:a5:91:b8:f3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::840:a5ff:fe91:b8f3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
147: vethc49639f@if146: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether a6:f3:3b:c1:52:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::a4f3:3bff:fec1:52be/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@jon-server:/home/root/logs#
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `mii-monitor-interval: 100` under the parameters section. Generate and apply again.

Comment: This seems to be an answer, not a comment...

Comment: As far as I can tell, this isn't working. I also attempted `arp-interval` and `arp-ip-targets` parameters with no result.